# Rails 4 Generate Devise Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I'd like to generate some devise views for an application, but whenever I try to use the command `rails g devise:views`, I get a complex error, well above my understanding.

```
/Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007ff613f5bb10 @paths=["/Users/michaeldunnegan/projects/SoundShare/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007ff6168369e0>]> (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/projects/SoundShare/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

One of these lines, `/Users/michaeldunnegan/projects/SoundShare/config/environment.rb:4:in`'`

is interesting. All I have in that file is:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

SoundShare::Application.initialize! # this is the line
```

Comment: Does that happen just when trying to generate devise views, or when you execute any generator or rake task? If the latter, it looks like there might be an issue in your routes file.

Comment: what is your devise gem version?

Comment: In gemfile: gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'. As a matter of fact, this does happen every time I try to use generate or rake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. make sure you have the `devise` gem compatible with rails 4 `gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.0.rc' #or higher`
2. run `bundle update`
3. Remove `devise.rb` in `initializers`, then run `devise:install` again to install new configs in intializers.
4. make sure you run `devise` model generator, for example `rails g devise User`
5. now you should be able to run: `rails g devise:views`

**Edit**

After working in teamviewer on Mike's computer, we took a copy of `devise.rb` from a working project on rails 4 and place it in `config/initializers/`

Next we ran the `rails generate devise:install` command and it said something back about a deprecation and asked us if we want to replace the content of `devise.rb` file. We accepted it and after this all devise commands worked well.

Comment: First: I didn't have a devise.rb file in my initializer folder. Second: when I ran 'rails g devise:install', I get the error in my original post

Comment: see if you can join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35947/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18344517-rails-4-generate-devise-views

Comment: ight. I joined the chat